# Loading the previous revision of a node

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-nodes

When you get a node, how do you load the previous version (revision)?

I know how loading a revision but not how getting the previous revision number ($node->vid is the current revision).

thanks

Comment: Did you mean the previous (as opposite of next) revision of a node?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposing that you have a node object `$node`, you can use the following code to get the previous revision.

```
$previous_vid = db_result( 
  db_query('SELECT MAX(vid) AS vid FROM {node_revisions} WHERE vid < %d AND nid = %d', $node->vid, $node->nid)
);
```

Once you have the previous revision, you can load the new node object with `node_load(array('nid' => $node-nid, 'vid' => $previous_vid))`.

The code should check if `db_result()` returns `FALSE`, in the case there isn't a previous revision.
To note that the field `vid` is global for each node; it doesn't contain the same value for different nodes.

Comment: My reply I have given is valid if you meant "the previous version (revision)". You wrote "the preview version (revision)".

Comment: Thanks. I change in the text for future reference.

Comment: The above is for Drupal 6.  Here's a Drupal 7 version:                               $previous_vid = db_query("SELECT MAX(vid) AS vid FROM {node_revision} WHERE vid < :vid AND nid = :nid", array(':vid' => $node->vid, ':nid' => $node->nid))->fetchField();

  if(isset($previous_vid)) {
    $prev =  node_load($node->nid, $previous_vid);
  }

Answer (score 3):

Thanks all.

I found also an other solution:

```
  $revisions = node_revision_list($node);
  next($revisions);
  if ($preview_key = key($revisions)) {
    $preview_revision = $revisions[$preview_key];
    $old_node = node_load($node->nid, $preview_revision->vid);
  }
```

But if you have a lot of revision you get a big array.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're trying to do; you want to get the preview of the node after someone submits changes?

The preview button has its own submit handler, [`node_form_build_preview()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/node_form_build_preview/6). There, it creates a new node object using the data in `$form_state` and runs [`node_preview()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/node_preview/6), which returns the markup for the preview.

If you want to capture that preview when the user clicks the preview button, you'll need to use [`hook_form_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_alter/6) to add another submit handler to the preview button:

```
$['form']['buttons']['preview']['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_custom_preview';
```

where mymodule_custom_preview is the name of your custom submit function. Take a look at [`node_form_build_preview()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/node_form_build_preview/6) for guidance, but your submit function is going to look something like this:

```
function mymodule_custom_preview($form, &$form_state) {
  $node = node_form_submit_build_node($form, $form_state);
  $preview = node_preview($node);
}
```

Also take a look at [`node_form()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/node_form/6), which gives you an idea of how the node form is structured. When you're all done, you're going to have code in your module that looks something like this:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if (strstr($form_id, '_node_form') !== FALSE) {
    $['form']['buttons']['preview']['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_custom_preview';
  }
}

function mymodule_custom_preview($form, &$form_state) {
  $node = node_form_submit_build_node($form, $form_state);
  $preview = node_preview($node);

  // Do what you will with $preview.
}
```

Comment: no i mean the previous revision of a node. Sorry. But thanks i learn something else :)